# Breaking a repetitive file in to instances of classes in python

Tags: python, text-parsing

For the first time I've decided to play about with some classes in Python, and I *think* this is an example of a task that would actually benefit from their use.

I'm trying to parse the ouput text file from a bioinformatics tool, but I'm not sure what the best way to proceed will be.

The file contains several distinct 'sections' of data, all of which I'd like to collect. The section I'm most interested in is somewhat delimited by `>>` strings (i.e. the file contains `>>` Result 1 `>>` Result 2 `>>` etc...)

I'm at a bit of a loss for the best way to start separating out the chunks I want without opening and reading the file over and over again (especially since the files have the possibility of being large).

```
ClusterBlast scores for /home/wms_joe/PVCs/other_genomes/multigene/operon_genbank/PVCcif_ATCC43949.gbk

Table of genes, locations, strands and annotations of query cluster:
PAU_01961   8   457 +   T4-like_virus_tail_tube_protein_gp19    no_locus_tag    
PAU_01962   521 1618    +   major_tail_sheath_protein   no_locus_tag    
PAU_01963   1799    3280    +   tail_sheath_protein no_locus_tag    
PAU_01964   3334    4533    +   tail_sheath_protein no_locus_tag    
PAU_01965   4547    5005    +   T4-like_virus_tail_tube_protein_gp19    no_locus_tag    
PAU_01966   5002    5181    +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag    
PAU_01967   5168    5851    +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag    
PAU_01968   5848    7449    +   Rhs_element_Vgr_protein no_locus_tag    
PAU_01969   7462    7905    +   baseplate_wedge_subunit no_locus_tag    
PAU_01970   7902    8318    +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag    
PAU_01971   8527    11253   +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag    
PAU_01972   11246   14197   +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag    
PAU_01973   14333   15184   +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag    
PAU_01974   15247   17145   +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag    
PAU_01975   17155   19227   +   ATP-dependent_zinc_metalloprotease_FtsH no_locus_tag    
PAU_01976   19252   20166   +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag    
PAU_01977   20327   21223   +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag    
PAU_01978   21308   22291   +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag    
PAU_01979   22788   23684   +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag    
PAU_01980   23656   24114   +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag    


Significant hits: 
1. PAU_1    Photorhabdus asymbiotica strain ATCC43949.

2. PAB_1    Photorhabdus asymbiotica strain Beaudesert.

3. PAN_5    Photorhabdus asymbiotica strain Nepal.

4. PAT_0    Photorhabdus asymbiotica strain Thai.


Details:

>>

1. PAU_1
Source: Photorhabdus asymbiotica strain ATCC43949.

Number of proteins with BLAST hits to this cluster: 31
MultiGeneBlast score: 31.7
Cumulative Blast bit score: 64022

Table of genes, locations, strands and annotations of subject cluster:
PAU_01961   2233799 2234248 +   T4-like_virus_tail_tube_protein_gp19    no_locus_tag
PAU_01962   2234312 2235409 +   major_tail_sheath_protein   no_locus_tag
PAU_01963   2235590 2237071 +   tail_sheath_protein no_locus_tag
PAU_01964   2237125 2238324 +   tail_sheath_protein no_locus_tag
PAU_01965   2238338 2238796 +   T4-like_virus_tail_tube_protein_gp19    no_locus_tag
PAU_01966   2238793 2238972 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAU_01967   2238959 2239642 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAU_01968   2239639 2241240 +   Rhs_element_Vgr_protein no_locus_tag
PAU_01969   2241253 2241696 +   baseplate_wedge_subunit no_locus_tag
PAU_01970   2241693 2242109 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAU_01971   2242318 2245044 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAU_01972   2245037 2247988 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAU_01973   2248124 2248975 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAU_01974   2249038 2250936 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAU_01976   2253043 2253957 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAU_01977   2254118 2255014 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAU_01978   2255099 2256082 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAU_01979   2256579 2257475 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAU_01980   2257447 2257905 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag

Table of Blast hits (query gene, subject gene, %identity, blast score, %coverage, e-value):
PAU_01961   PAU_01961   100 309 100.0   2e-108  
PAU_01962   PAU_01962   100 749 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01963   PAU_01963   100 1015    100.0   0.0 
PAU_01964   PAU_01964   100 821 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01965   PAU_01965   100 312 100.0   2e-109  
PAU_01966   PAU_01966   100 117 100.0   1e-35   
PAU_01967   PAU_01967   100 471 100.0   1e-169  
PAU_01968   PAU_01968   100 1095    100.0   0.0 
PAU_01969   PAU_01969   100 298 100.0   5e-104  
PAU_01970   PAU_01970   100 277 100.0   3e-96   
PAU_01971   PAU_01971   100 1866    100.0   0.0 
PAU_01972   PAU_01972   100 2034    100.0   0.0 
PAU_01973   PAU_01973   100 583 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01974   PAU_01974   100 1273    100.0   0.0 
PAU_01976   PAU_01976   100 614 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01977   PAU_01977   100 604 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01978   PAU_01978   100 676 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01979   PAU_01979   100 608 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01980   PAU_01980   100 300 100.0   1e-104  



>>

2. PAB_1
Source: Photorhabdus asymbiotica strain Beaudesert.

Number of proteins with BLAST hits to this cluster: 31
MultiGeneBlast score: 31.7
Cumulative Blast bit score: 62512

Table of genes, locations, strands and annotations of subject cluster:
cmlA    528550  528990  +   Chloramphenicol_acetyltransferase_2 no_locus_tag
PAB_00496   530556  531005  +   T4-like_virus_tail_tube_protein_gp19    no_locus_tag
PAB_00497   531069  532169  +   major_tail_sheath_protein   no_locus_tag
PAB_00498   532217  533698  +   tail_sheath_protein no_locus_tag
PAB_00499   533752  534951  +   tail_sheath_protein no_locus_tag
PAB_00500   534965  535423  +   T4-like_virus_tail_tube_protein_gp19    no_locus_tag
PAB_00501   535420  535599  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAB_00502   535586  536269  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAB_00503   536266  537867  +   Rhs_element_Vgr_protein no_locus_tag
PAB_00504   537880  538323  +   baseplate_wedge_subunit no_locus_tag
PAB_00505   538320  538733  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAB_00506   538802  541537  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAB_00507   541530  544499  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAB_00508   544638  545486  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAB_00509   545549  547444  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
ftsH_1  547454  549538  +   ATP-dependent_zinc_metalloprotease_FtsH no_locus_tag
PAB_00511   549563  550462  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAB_00512   550627  551526  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAB_00516   554417  555034  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAB_00517   555006  555464  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
dsdX_1  555806  557191  -   DsdX_permease   no_locus_tag
srlR_1  558367  559143  -   Glucitol_operon_repressor   no_locus_tag
ygbM    559155  559934  -   Putative_hydroxypyruvate_isomerase_YgbM no_locus_tag
fucA_1  560079  560714  -   L-fuculose_phosphate_aldolase   no_locus_tag

Table of Blast hits (query gene, subject gene, %identity, blast score, %coverage, e-value):
PAU_01961   PAB_00496   99  308 100.0   5e-108  
PAU_01962   PAB_00497   91  692 100.273972603   0.0 
PAU_01963   PAB_00498   84  803 101.419878296   0.0 
PAU_01964   PAB_00499   92  770 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01965   PAB_00500   96  302 99.3421052632   2e-105  
PAU_01966   PAB_00501   98  115 100.0   6e-35   
PAU_01967   PAB_00502   95  453 100.0   2e-162  
PAU_01968   PAB_00503   94  1039    100.0   0.0 
PAU_01969   PAB_00504   93  280 100.0   1e-96   
PAU_01970   PAB_00505   89  248 100.0   2e-84   
PAU_01971   PAB_00506   84  1572    100.330396476   0.0 
PAU_01972   PAB_00507   84  1706    100.915564598   0.0 
PAU_01973   PAB_00508   72  410 100.706713781   9e-144  
PAU_01974   PAB_00509   79  992 100.316455696   0.0 
PAU_01975   ftsH_1  77  1095    100.579710145   0.0 
PAU_01976   PAB_00511   83  507 98.6842105263   0.0 
PAU_01977   PAB_00512   87  533 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01979   PAB_00516   95  396 68.7919463087   3e-139  
PAU_01980   PAB_00517   96  291 100.0   4e-101  



>>

3. PAN_5
Source: Photorhabdus asymbiotica strain Nepal.

Number of proteins with BLAST hits to this cluster: 29
MultiGeneBlast score: 29.2
Cumulative Blast bit score: 61588

Table of genes, locations, strands and annotations of subject cluster:
tdiR    3118573 3119202 +   Transcriptional_regulatory_protein_TdiR no_locus_tag
xerD_3  3123014 3123238 -   Tyrosine_recombinase_XerD   no_locus_tag
PAN_02769   3124026 3124475 +   T4-like_virus_tail_tube_protein_gp19    no_locus_tag
PAN_02770   3124539 3125639 +   major_tail_sheath_protein   no_locus_tag
PAN_02771   3125687 3127156 +   tail_sheath_protein no_locus_tag
PAN_02772   3127210 3128409 +   tail_sheath_protein no_locus_tag
PAN_02773   3128423 3128881 +   T4-like_virus_tail_tube_protein_gp19    no_locus_tag
PAN_02774   3128878 3129057 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAN_02775   3129044 3129727 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAN_02776   3129724 3131325 +   Rhs_element_Vgr_protein no_locus_tag
PAN_02777   3131338 3131781 +   baseplate_wedge_subunit no_locus_tag
PAN_02778   3131778 3132191 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAN_02779   3132260 3134998 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAN_02780   3134991 3137954 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAN_02781   3138093 3138938 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAN_02782   3139001 3140908 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAN_02784   3143027 3143926 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAN_02785   3144090 3144989 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAN_02789   3146760 3147656 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAN_02790   3147628 3148086 +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
hcpA_11 3148136 3148615 -   Secreted_protein_hcp    no_locus_tag
ygbN    3148802 3150187 -   Inner_membrane_permease_YgbN    no_locus_tag

Table of Blast hits (query gene, subject gene, %identity, blast score, %coverage, e-value):
PAU_01961   PAN_02769   99  308 100.0   5e-108  
PAU_01962   PAN_02770   91  691 100.273972603   0.0 
PAU_01963   PAN_02771   85  810 100.60851927    0.0 
PAU_01964   PAN_02772   92  769 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01965   PAN_02773   97  305 99.3421052632   1e-106  
PAU_01966   PAN_02774   98  115 100.0   6e-35   
PAU_01967   PAN_02775   95  452 100.0   3e-162  
PAU_01968   PAN_02776   94  1040    100.0   0.0 
PAU_01969   PAN_02777   93  280 100.0   1e-96   
PAU_01970   PAN_02778   90  251 100.0   9e-86   
PAU_01971   PAN_02779   84  1571    100.660792952   0.0 
PAU_01972   PAN_02780   84  1701    100.915564598   0.0 
PAU_01973   PAN_02781   70  407 100.706713781   1e-142  
PAU_01974   PAN_02782   79  981 100.949367089   0.0 
PAU_01976   PAN_02784   82  503 98.6842105263   1e-179  
PAU_01977   PAN_02785   87  536 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01979   PAN_02789   94  572 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01980   PAN_02790   97  296 100.0   5e-103  



>>

4. PAT_0
Source: Photorhabdus asymbiotica strain Thai.

Number of proteins with BLAST hits to this cluster: 29
MultiGeneBlast score: 29.2
Cumulative Blast bit score: 61577

Table of genes, locations, strands and annotations of subject cluster:
PAT_00132   127877  128326  +   T4-like_virus_tail_tube_protein_gp19    no_locus_tag
PAT_00133   128390  129490  +   major_tail_sheath_protein   no_locus_tag
PAT_00134   129538  131007  +   tail_sheath_protein no_locus_tag
PAT_00135   131061  132260  +   tail_sheath_protein no_locus_tag
PAT_00136   132274  132732  +   T4-like_virus_tail_tube_protein_gp19    no_locus_tag
PAT_00137   132729  132908  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAT_00138   132895  133578  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAT_00139   133575  135176  +   Rhs_element_Vgr_protein no_locus_tag
PAT_00140   135189  135632  +   baseplate_wedge_subunit no_locus_tag
PAT_00141   135629  136042  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAT_00142   136111  138885  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAT_00143   138878  141841  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAT_00144   141980  142825  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAT_00145   142888  144795  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAT_00147   146914  147813  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAT_00148   147977  148876  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAT_00152   150647  151543  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
PAT_00153   151515  151973  +   hypothetical_protein    no_locus_tag
hcpA_1  152023  152502  -   Secreted_protein_hcp    no_locus_tag

Table of Blast hits (query gene, subject gene, %identity, blast score, %coverage, e-value):
PAU_01961   PAT_00132   99  308 100.0   5e-108  
PAU_01962   PAT_00133   91  693 100.273972603   0.0 
PAU_01963   PAT_00134   85  810 100.60851927    0.0 
PAU_01964   PAT_00135   92  769 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01965   PAT_00136   97  305 99.3421052632   1e-106  
PAU_01966   PAT_00137   98  115 100.0   6e-35   
PAU_01967   PAT_00138   95  452 100.0   3e-162  
PAU_01968   PAT_00139   94  1039    100.0   0.0 
PAU_01969   PAT_00140   93  280 100.0   1e-96   
PAU_01970   PAT_00141   89  249 100.0   5e-85   
PAU_01971   PAT_00142   83  1568    101.982378855   0.0 
PAU_01972   PAT_00143   84  1701    100.915564598   0.0 
PAU_01973   PAT_00144   70  407 100.706713781   1e-142  
PAU_01974   PAT_00145   78  974 100.949367089   0.0 
PAU_01976   PAT_00147   82  503 98.6842105263   1e-179  
PAU_01977   PAT_00148   87  536 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01979   PAT_00152   94  572 100.0   0.0 
PAU_01980   PAT_00153   97  296 100.0   5e-103
```

The file goes on and on in the same way as the last few results between the `>>` that I mentioned.

The first 2 sections of the file (`ClusterBlast scores...` and `Significant hits` only appear once, but for every result denoted by the `>>`, I was thinking to collect each one as a separate class instance with various attributes and functions that I'll want to write accordingly once I've sorted out how to separate the file segments.

Each of the results I'm thinking to collect in to a Class something like:

```
class MGB_hit(object):
    """
    Store each MGB hit as a class object so as to group all the attributes.

    Attributes:
        hit_no: The rank number of the hit returned from MultiGeneBlast.
        name: The name assigned to the hit rank.
        source: The extended description of the hit/its sequence origin.
        protein_no: The number of proteins with hits in the detected cluster.
        MGB_score: The weighted MGB score used to rank the hits with synteny etc.
        cubit_score: The cumulative bit-score of all the BLAST hits within the cluster.
    """

    def __init__(self, hit_no, name, source, protein_no, MGB_score, cubit_score):
        """Initialise a MGB hit object"""
        self.hit_no = 0
        self.name = ""
        self.source = ""
        self.protein_no = 0
        self.MGB_score = 0
        self.cubit_score = 0
```

Which would mean populating a list of each class instance from the input file (and also handing the first 2 segments, maybe as classes of their own?).

### Edit

Managed to get some amount of the way there, with the following:

```
def parse_section(file, delim1, delim2):
    """Separate files in to sections according to delimiter pairs"""

    import re
    regex = '{}(.*?){}'.format(delim1,delim2)
    for result in re.findall(regex, file, re.S):
        result = filter(None, result.split('\n'))

        return result

def main():
    """Call functions and parse results."""

    args = get_args()
    header_section = []
    sighits_section = []
    details_section = []
    with open(args.clusterfile,'r') as cfh:
        content = cfh.read()
        header_section.append(parse_section(content,"^", "Significant hits"))
        sighits_section.append(parse_section(content,"Significant hits",">>"))
        details_section.append(parse_section(content, ">>", ">>"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However this only gives me the first of the matches where the `>>` delimiters begin. Any suggestions for capturing the others?

Comment: You actually do not need those parameters on `__init__`  (except `self`) as you seem to not be using them.

Comment: I'm still getting to grips with the classes so you may well be right. I'm planning to use them later on (once I've written more methods). It's not 100% clear to me just yet what needs to be included with an init or not, but I'm getting there..!

Comment: I usually include on init data I need to build up my object. In your case I think you intended to use those variables to initialize your instance's attributes. If that's the case, just set them like `self.hit_no = hit_no` instead of initializing with a fixed value.